# Allow querystring to have two params through ``?``

Tags: javascript, parameters, query-string

Will it be a mistake to have querystring like: `http://example.com?id=12345?fileName=test.csv` ?

`POST` works but is it consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it would be a mistake, multiple parameters should be done using `&`, like so:

```
http://example.com?id=12345&fileName=test.csv
```

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) has the following to say:

> W3C recommends that all web servers support semicolon separators in
>   addition to ampersand separators[6] to allow
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings in URLs within HTML
>   documents without having to entity escape ampersands.

Notice it mentions semicolons and ampersands only, nothing about question marks. It also implies that semi-colons are only a recommendation on top of the standard ampersand separator.

It is also worth considering that because ampersands are considered to be the standard, then developers who need to split a query string will likely split it on `&` and may not even realize that other separators should be considered. This may also hold true for the use of any 3rd party libraries that need to manipulate query strings.

Comment: @Kosmetika: And what technology is handling the request? It may not work in all environments, and it is certainly not the recommended approach (I will edit in a link when I find a good one)